# Woocommerce: How to remove "Archive" in title?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I'm trying to remove the word "*Archive*" from the page title.

How to remove it? By adding a filter?

Example:

> My collections **Archive** | My sitename

Answer (score 31):

Best to use Wordpress SEO by Yoast.

Within Titles & Metas go to the Taxonomies tab and update the Title template for Product Categories to remove the word Archive. Mine ended up looking like this:

%%term_title%% %%page%% %%sep%% %%sitename%%

Answer (score 15):

you can rewrite the filter in functions.php so it fails, causing WooCommerce not the render it.

```
function override_page_title() {
return false;
}
add_filter('woocommerce_show_page_title', 'override_page_title');
```

Comment: Or, single line: add_filter('woocommerce_show_page_title', '__return_false');

Comment: Or, `add_filter( 'woocommerce_show_page_title', function() { return false; } );`

Comment: i guess this is the wrong answer, since op asked for the title-tag (not really clear, but his code snippet above looks like it). but i was searching for THIS answer. i wanted to remove the archive title from the page template and this is what this function does, so i'm good with this :)

Answer (score 15):

If you are using the Yoast SEO (Versión 8.1.2), the options were move to:

Yoast SEO -> Search Appearance -> Taxonomies.

[image]

In there look up by Product categories (product_cat) and open it.

[image]

Then remove the Archives string from the head.

Answer (score 7):

I know this is an old post but I tried the answers here and it didn't work.
I found the solution basing it off renegadesk's answer, but in addition of going to the Taxonomies Tab I also had to change it in the Post Types tab. See below:

Get Wordpress SEO by Yoast if you don't already have it, then click SEO > Titles & Metas > Post Types. Scroll down and look for the heading "Custom Post Type Archives". On the "Products", you can edit the content of this title. Mine now looks like this:

```
%%pt_plural%% %%page%% %%sep%% %%sitename%%
```

Comment: Thought that I should mention that Woocommerce by default does not show `Products Archive` in the title. It is actually Yoast SEO that introduced it, and then make you jump through hoops to remove it. 

If you disable Yoast SEO, you will see that `Archive` disappears from the title. But if you must use Yoast, they do have one FAQ that tells you exactly how to remove `Archive`

Comment: These days, the path is: SEO -> Search Appearance -> Taxonomies; then check the makeup of the field SEO title.

Answer (score 0):

In woocommerce there seem to be 3 instances of Archives (case sensitive) one in 
\wp-content\plugins\woocommerce\woocommerce-hooks.php around line 50
and 2 in \wp-content\plugins\woocommerce\woocommerce-template.php 
around lines 240 ish
Perhaps one of those is what you're looking for and you may be able to modify code.

Answer (score 0):

in addition to Ted C:

For this purpose Wordpress has already predifined functions starting with __return_.
In this case the function you are looking for is __return_false.

add_filter('woocommerce_show_page_title', '__return_false',10,0); will also work.

The last two params are the order of the function and the number of params passed to it.

It is always a good pratice to set them up but this is only necessary if you want to modify the default order (10) and the number of params passed (1).

Answer (score 0):

You have this filter for all cases : "get_the_archive_title".
But then there are different cases.

For exemple for simple category you can do :

```
function prefix_category_title( $title ) {
  if(is_category()){
    $title = single_cat_title( '', false );
  }
  return $title;
}
add_filter( 'get_the_archive_title', 'prefix_category_title' );
```

For custom post type you should do :

```
function prefix_category_title( $title ) {
  if(is_archive('slug-of-your-custom-post-type')){
    $title = single_cat_title( '', false );
  }
  return $title;
}
add_filter( 'get_the_archive_title', 'prefix_category_title' );
```

So finally you have many condition like :

- is_category
- is_archive
- is_tag
- is_author
- is_year
- is_tax

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_archive_title/

Vincent.

Answer (score -4):

wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates/archive-product.php

Edit this file archive-product.php and remove the below 3 lines.

```
                    <h1 class="page-title"><?php woocommerce_page_title(); ?></h1>

            <?php endif; ?>
```

This will remove page title on shop page and all other pages.

Comment: The question is looking to remove a specific word from the title, not the whole title itself.